# Regex Invalid quantifier?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using regexes with JavaScript and I'm having some trouble with one that returns me `Invalid quantifier ?`.

This is the code:

```
if(url.match(new RegExp('^https?://.+/foresee(?:-|_)surveydef\.js(?:\?)(.*)','g')) != null)
```

I read on other questions that I need to add a `\` before the `?` character but it does not fix it...

```
if(url.match(new RegExp('^https\?://.+/foresee(\?:-|_)surveydef\.js(\?:\?)(.*)','g')) != null)
```

The input url is `http://marvel.com/`, I just check for a match.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713290/javascript-invalid-quantifier-in-regex. Also, what is your input string? What is the expected behavior? There are potentially several issues (you are using a regex with a global modifier with `match`, that means all captured values are lost.

Comment: You need to escape those slashes. And, given that you appear to be attempting to match a URL, I'd recommend escaping the dots too.

Comment: Ok, the `http://marvel.com/` does not contain a `?`. Using `\\?` won't help. What are the requirements? Match any URL?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there can be different url's to match. I need to check if the url matches the regex expression.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz I tried this, but the error is still there: `'events\.foreseeresults\.com\/rec\/process\?(.*)','g'`

Comment: Well, what expression should a URL match?

Comment: Works in Chrome console, with `'?'` or with `'\?'` either way

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was wrong about the code that caused the error...it was caused by another `else` statement that was on the same line (the code is not written by me). I updated my question, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the following code:

```
if(url.match(new RegExp('^https?://.+/foresee(?:-|_)surveydef\.js(\\?:\?)(.*)','g'))
```

Comment: What are you doing with `(\\?:\?)`? Why use a RegExp constructor at all if your pattern is static? Your question is still unclear as you have not provided the input and expected output. Matching a `?` followed with an optional `:` does not make much sense.